# How cache is managed?

Tags: android, caching

I am writing an application where i m planning to store the Images read from server to Android cache. As I read somewhere "Android cache can be cleared by system whenever the memory is low", so if I image is removed how will i get the indication that the image is removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no way to know wether Android has cleared the cache. But if you save data to the cache folder you can hold on to the filename and check wether the file is present or not.

I have a download task for my data which checks the cache first and if there is no data present the download starts. Otherwise the cached file is used.

Answer (score 0):

For clearing app cache put this code in onDestroy()

protected void onDestroy() { super.onDestroy();

```
    try {
        trimCache(this);
       // Toast.makeText(this,"onDestroy " ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
public static void trimCache(Context context) {
    try {
       File dir = context.getCacheDir();
       if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
          deleteDir(dir);
       }
    } catch (Exception e) {
       // TODO: handle exception
    }
 }

 public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
       String[] children = dir.list();
       for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
          boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
          if (!success) {
             return false;
          }
       }
    }

    // The directory is now empty so delete it
    return dir.delete();
 }
```